# logical error with random number guessing game

Tags: java, random

In this program, the computer generates a random number (between 1-100) and the user attempts to guess it.
Runs until the user correctly guesses the number. Needs to print out the total number of tries it took before the number was guessed correctly.
Program runs fine, but there is a logical error. Nothing prints out when I correctly guess the number; the program just stops instead.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Problem3 {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 

    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = rand.nextInt(100)+1;
    System.out.println(num); //prints out the random number so I know test works correctly
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println("Guess the random number. The number is between 1 and 100. Enter it below");
    console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess = console.nextInt();
    while(guess != num){  //while guess is not = to number  
      if(guess < num){             //if less than num
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low"); 
        System.out.println("Guess the random number. The number is between 1 and 100. Enter it below");
        guess = console.nextInt();
        count++;
      }else if( guess > num){      //if greater than num   
          System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
          System.out.println("Guess the random number. The number is between 1 and 100. Enter it below");
          guess = console.nextInt();
          count++;
      }else{
        count++;
        System.out.println("You guessed correctly after " + count + " tries!");
    }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you never enter the `else` stage, because when the number is guessed, the `while` code won't execute and therefore the `else` code will never execute. So after that the number is guessed, so condition is `false`, exit `while` loop and `System.out.print` the Congrats message

Put this outside your while loop "at the end":

```
 System.out.println("You guessed correctly after " + count + " tries!");
```

Here's what your code should look like:

```
while(guess != num){  //while guess is not = to number  
      if(guess < num){             //if less than num
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low"); 
        System.out.println("Guess the random number. The number is between 1 and 100. Enter it below");
        guess = console.nextInt();
        count++;
      }else{      //if greater than num   
          System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
          System.out.println("Guess the random number. The number is between 1 and 100. Enter it below");
          guess = console.nextInt();
          count++;
      }
    }

  System.out.println("You guessed correctly after " + ++count + " tries!");
```

Comment: Thanks! can you explain why this has to go outside the while loop? Basically the program ignored the last "else" statement?

Comment: Exactly, the last else statement is never executed because, when you read from the keyboard, you go back to check if the condition was true in while loop. If the number is guessed, you don't enter the while loop again, so the else statement won't be reached in any ways. @foodnliquor

Comment: Could I fix that by testing outside the while loop: if( guess == num){ S.o.println("You guessed correctly after " + count + " tries!");

Comment: The point is that if you exit the while loop, it means that the condition was false, which is in your case, Number guessed, so No need for the check again @foodnliquor

Comment: No problem, I posted the code if you want to check it. Please mark the question solved if you don't have any other questions :) @foodnliquor

Comment: You may want to double check your answer @AmirBawab. The resulting count will be one short.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop condition becomes false when the correct number is guessed. This makes the else unreachable.

**EDIT**

Here is how I would have tackled your problem. If you find yourself repeating code, it usually means there is an opportunity for improvement. Not only is there less code, but it is easier to read and follow what is going on. I'm not trying to steal the answer (@AmirBawab found the issue first), but I am a big believer in not just making code that works, but code that can be maintained and read by others. Hopefully as you continue learning you will keep that in mind. Happy coding!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;

    int count = 0;

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Guess the random number. The number is between 1 and 100. Enter it below");
        int guess = console.nextInt();
        count++;
        if (guess < num) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
        } else if (guess > num) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You guessed correctly after " + count + " tries!");
            break;
        }
    }

    console.close();

}
```

Comment: Should i remove that last else statement all together and make it an if statement outside of the while loop?

Comment: Replace with `while(true)` and break in your else.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that as well. But I think my professor wants us to avoid using things we haven't learned officially in class yet. But I do know how that works.

Comment: @foodnliquor please see my edit. Hopefully that will help in the future when designing your programming solutions.

Comment: Thanks dcharms! Your code is a lot cleaner than what I started with